# Icons in Table of Contents

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

[image]

This image provides a rough approximation of something I'd like to do in my book's ToC. I would like the sections within **only one** of my chapters to utilize a unique icon. For the sake of time, I've only provided an example for the first section. However, I'd like a unique icon to be used for each of the sections within one chapter. It is fine if the section numbers are retained; I just need the image to appear before the text of the section title.

I'm lost about how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

(I am using the `book` class.)

Comment: Are you a *bundle* of pictures (one for each section)? Is it only a icon for all sections? is it necessary to make it using some *graphic package* as `tikz` or ...?

Comment: So the icon is *not* supposed to occur in the section heading itself (i.e. on page 3, in the example)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package.

Use `\iconsectioninToC` just before the `\chapter`(s) in which you want to add the icon in the ToC; return to the standard formatting using `\stdsectioninToC`.

In the definition of `\iconsectioninToC` change the settings for the `\includegraphics` command and adjust the lengths to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stdsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\newcommand\iconsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}%
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{image-5}}\hspace{0.5em}% change here 
  }
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\stdsectioninToC}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{First test section}
\section{Second test section}
\section{Third test section}
\section{Fourth test section}

\iconsectioninToC
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{First test section}
\section{Second test section}
\section{Third test section}
\section{Fourth test section}

\stdsectioninToC
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{First test section}
\section{Second test section}
\section{Third test section}
\section{Fourth test section}

\end{document}
```

The resulting ToC:

[image]
If each section entry has to receive its own image, you can use this simply variation, which assumes your image files are named `image-1`, `image-2`, `image-3`, etc.:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{mysecimage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\stdsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\newcommand\iconsectioninToC{
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}%
    \stepcounter{mysecimage}%
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{image-\the\value{mysecimage}}}\hspace{0.5em}% change here 
  }
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\stdsectioninToC}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{First test section}
\section{Second test section}
\section{Third test section}
\section{Fourth test section}

\iconsectioninToC
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{First test section}
\section{Second test section}
\section{Third test section}
\section{Fourth test section}

\stdsectioninToC
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{First test section}
\section{Second test section}
\section{Third test section}
\section{Fourth test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Gonzalo, that is EXACTLY what I am after. However, I want to use a unique image for each of the sections. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: @LarryTate sure, it's possible. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I would have never figured that out. Thanks for your help, Gonzalo.

Comment: @LarryTate You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: I'm not good enough to understand all that is going on in your code here. What is the purpose of the \stdsectioninToC command? Hopefully, I can get this to work in my book.

Comment: @LarryTate When you use `\iconsectioninToC`, the section entries in the ToC automatically will get an associated image. To return to the standrad settings (with no images added), you need to use `\stdsectioninToC`.

Comment: I've just noticed that using this method in my document makes the TOC hyperlinks to the sections not function properly. While there are are links for each section, they do not link to the proper place in the chapter. All the links seem to go to a single place near the beginning of the chapter. Is there some easy fix here?

Comment: Can this be done with tikz?

Comment: @LarryTate, yes, see this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297770/64741